# How to use AWS Code Artifact with custom repository providers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codeartifact

When creating a repository in AWS Code Artifact a user may optionally specify external repositories to act as upstreams for created repository. This is provided from a list as follows:

- Maven Central
- Commonsware
- Google Android Store
- Gradle Plugins Store
- NPM
- Nuget
- Pypi

The CLI counterpart associate-external-connection seems to be limited to those 7 upstreams as well.

Considering my usecase is to use code artifact as pull through cache for a public repository (for example jitpack) that is not listed as possible connection, how does one provide a "custom URL" to act as upstream, and which "protocol" (in this case, maven) should be used to access it?